# How should I construct a prior distribution with a particular kind of count data

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, prior, gamma-distribution, posterior

For context I will first explain the overall problem that I am working on.  I am given a catalog of product names and I am also given a large text dataset that may contain mentions of these catalog products.  The problem is that the actual product name in the catalog can be very different from how it is mentioned in the text dataset (therefore regex would not produce very good results).  Furthermore, there are many product names (or parts of product names) that are ambiguous which means that they can be present in the text dataset but not necessarily refer to the product in the catalog.

The evidence that I am using is the measure of how strong the match is between the catalog product name and the mention in the text (this is done with minimum-edit-distance).

I want to try to inject some prior information in order to solve some of these problems.  The prior information that I have and think would be useful is a measure of popularity of each product in the catalog.  My hypothesis is that popular products are more likely to be mentioned and any candidate mention that is also a very popular product should have its posterior probability of P(catalog_entry | mention_text) boosted and vice versa.  I am using wikipedia pageviews of the the wikipedia article associated with the product in the catalog as a proxy for its popularity (note that all catalog products are within the same product type/category so the pageviews should be an accurate representation of relative popularity).

So my question is what is the best way to tranform the pageview data into probabilities (i.e. what is the best distribution to model the pageview data with).  Pageviews are discrete so I suppose I need a discrete distribution where there is a large probability mass at high values.  But pageviews are also unbounded on the right.  At first I considered a Poisson distribution but it does really fit with what I want because at large enough values the probability mass will start decreasing.  I suppose that I could artificially bound the distribution between 0 and the largest pageview that I observe over all products and then use some kind of Gamma distribution.  However, a Gamma distribution is not discrete.  Can anyone see a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider the pageviews to be categorical, multinomial to be specific.  Thus a natural estimator to use as your prior would be the sample proportions

$p(\text{product j}) = \frac{ \text{totalnumber of page views for product j}}{\text{total number of page views for all products}}$

I assume you already have a model in mind for the minimum edit distance conditional on product j?  If so, then the posterior probability of product j would be

$ p( \text{product j } \vert \text{ text} ) = \frac{p( \text{text } \vert \text{ product j}) p( \text{product j}) }{ p(\text{text}) }$

where the denominator,

$p(\text{text}) = \sum_j p(\text{text } \vert \text{ product j}) p( \text{product j})$

Answer (score 0):

Why not perform a normalizing approximation to the data and perform subsequent computations?

Comment: This is brief enough that it's more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer. Answers require a bit more thought and work.